# sidekiq workers sending twilio calls in wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, sidekiq

I have an SMS app that sends the SMS message to be sent to a sidekiq worker, which then pings twilio to actually send the message. The problem I'm running into is that by sending the messages to a worker, sometimes messages above 160 characters get sent in the wrong order. I assume this is because sidekiq is running the jobs concurrently. How do I solve this problem?

Previously, I would cycle through each 160 characters of a message and send each 160 character string to a worker to be sent. This caused issues because the workers would get setup and run concurrently to the messages were out of order. To solve this, I moved the 160 character logic into the worker, which I believe solved the issue of a single message.

However, if multiple messages come through within 1-2 seconds, they get sent concurrently so it's possible it will be out of order again. How do I make sure sidekiq processes the messages in the order I call the perform_async method? Here's my code:

//messages_controller.rb

```
SendSMSWorker.new.perform(customer.id, message_text, 'sent', false, true)
```

//send_sms_worker.rb

```
def perform(customer_id, message_text, direction, viewed, via_api)
    customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
    company  = customer.company
    texts = message_text.scan(/.{1,160}/) # split the messages up into 160 char pieces
    texts.each do |text|
      message = customer.messages.new(
        user_id:     company.admin.id, # set the user_id to the admin's ID when using the api
        company_id:  company.id,
        text:        text,
        direction:   'sent',
        viewed:      false,
        via_api:     true
      )
      # send_sms returns nil if successful
      if error = message.send_sms
        customer.mark_as_invalid! if error.code == 21211
      else
        # only save the message if the SMS was successfully sent
        puts "API_SEND_MESSAGE company_id: #{company.id}, customer_id: #{customer.id}, message_id: #{message.id}, texts_count: #{texts.count}"
        message.save
        Helper.publish(company.admin, message.create_json_with_extra_attributes(true))
      end
    end
  end
```

to be clear, the message.send_sms is the method on the message model that actually sends the sms via twilio. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending multiple messages, each message takes it's own route to the destination carrier.  Even if they're sent in the correct sequence there isn't a guarantee they'll be received at the handset in the correct order.  A way to overcome this is using concatenated messages up to 1600 characters (in the US).  If you send a long message via the Messages resource it will be received as a single long message.  Just make sure you're using the Messages resource:

@client.account.messages.create()

instead of

client.account.sms.messages.create()

You can read more here:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters

http://twilio-ruby.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/messages.html

Comment: shoot...i should have been more clear...the messages aren't being SAVED in the right order to my database